# Command line chat for Google Hangounts in Mac OS X

Tags: osx, chat, command-line, google-hangouts

Is there any tool for using Google Hangouts chat in my Mac OS X terminal?

I Googled a lot but couldn't find one that works for Mac OS X; most of them are for Linux.

Comment: Any XMPP/Google Talk client should work fine with Hangouts.

Answer (score 1):

Found [Profanity](http://www.profanity.im)

Its XMPP based and works with Google chat(both old and new hangout chat).

You might want to enable [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) option and if you've enabled 2 step authentication, would want to use secure apps password.